# Python - plotting a specific line from different contour plots all on the same graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

If you run the code you will see that I'm displaying contour lines for the Momentum Capacity (variable AM - [Contour Line Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeqhU.png)) for different diameters. What I wish to do is to display the 2.0 contour line for different RPM values, while keeping the current X and Y axes.

Currently, RPM is a fixed value with which I compute AM. If for example, I increase the RPM, the 2.0 contour line will move "up", and "down" if I decrease it. I wish to display this variation in 2.0 contour line positioning. In the end, I want the graph to have a 4000 RPM 2.0 line, then a 4500 RPM 2.0 line, then a 5000 RPM 2.0 line, and so on.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import meshgrid

""" 
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Functions 
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
"""


def mm2m(value):
    return value * 10 ** (-3)


def m2mm(value):
    return value * 10 ** 3


def rpm2rad(value):
    return value * 2 * np.pi / 60


def get_percentage_diff(previous, current):
    try:
        percentage = abs(previous - current) / max(previous, current) * 100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        percentage = float('inf')
    if current < previous:
        percentage = - percentage
    return percentage


def angular_momentum(d1, d2):
    R1 = d1 / 2
    R2 = d2 / 2
    V = (np.pi * R1 ** 2 - np.pi * R2 ** 2) * width
    M = rho * V
    inertia = 1 / 2 * M * (R1 ** 2 + R2 ** 2)
    omega = rpm2rad(RPM)
    return inertia * omega


def angular_momentum_test(inertia, rpm):
    omega = rpm2rad(rpm)
    return inertia * omega


def get_inertia(d1, d2, w):
    R1 = d1 / 2
    R2 = d2 / 2
    V = (np.pi * R1 ** 2 - np.pi * R2 ** 2) * w
    M = rho * V
    return 1 / 2 * M * (R1 ** 2 + R2 ** 2)


def angular_momentum_rod(d1, d2):
    R1 = d1 / 2
    R2 = d2 / 2
    V = (np.pi * R1 ** 2 - np.pi * R2 ** 2) * rod_width
    M = rho * V
    inertia = 1 / 2 * M * (R1 ** 2 + R2 ** 2)
    omega = rpm2rad(RPM)
    return inertia * omega


""" 
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Input
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
"""

RPM = 6000
rho = 2700
width = mm2m(50)

rod_width = mm2m(250)
rod_diameter = mm2m(10)

""" 
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Calculation
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
"""

D1 = mm2m(np.arange(100, 150, 1))
D2 = mm2m(np.arange(50, 140, 1))
X, Y = meshgrid(D1, D2)
AM = angular_momentum(X, Y) + angular_momentum_rod(rod_diameter, 0)

# Testing Values
OD = mm2m(145)
ID = mm2m(80)
test_width = mm2m(60)
test_RPM = 6000
I_test = get_inertia(OD, ID, test_width) * 10 ** 6
AM_test = angular_momentum_test(I_test / 10 ** 6, test_RPM) + angular_momentum_rod(rod_diameter, 0)
Inventor_I_Value = 3190.667

# rod_I_test = get_inertia(mm2m(10),0,mm2m(250)) * 10 ** 6

""" 
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Printing
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
"""

print("The momentum capacity is: ", AM_test, " [Nms]\n")
print("The moment of inertia is: ", I_test,
      " [Nmm2] , diff: {} \n".format(get_percentage_diff(I_test, Inventor_I_Value)))
# print(rod_I_test)
""" 
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Plotting
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
"""

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=300)
ctr = plt.contour(X, Y, AM, np.arange(0, 10, 0.5), colors='k')
fil = plt.contourf(X, Y, AM, levels=200, cmap="turbo")
plt.grid(True, which='both', zorder=1, alpha=0.69, linewidth=0.75,linestyle='-')
plt.text(0.102, 0.132, " Width = {} [mm] \n \u03C1 = {} [kg/m3]\n RPM = {} ".format(m2mm(width), rho, RPM), style='normal',
         bbox={'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha': 1, 'pad': 10})
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.xlabel("Outer Diameter [m]")
plt.ylabel("Inner Diameter [m]")
plt.title("Flywheel Momentum Capacity [Nms]")
plt.clabel(ctr)
plt.colorbar(fil)
plt.savefig('Flywheel_Momentum_Capacity.png')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to set `levels=[2]` inside the `plt.contour` call.

I'm going to give you a recipe. Start by creating two lists with the same number of elements

```
RPMS = [4500, 5000, 5500, 6000]
colors = ["r", "g", "b", "k"]
```

Loop over each RPM, do the computation and plot it:

```
# this are needed to create a legend when using contour
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
labels, artists = [], []

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=300)

for RPM, col in zip(RPMS, colors):
    # do the computations

    # plotting
    plt.contour(X, Y, AM_, np.arange(0, 10, 0.5), levels=[2], colors=col)
    labels.append(str(RPM))
    artists.append(Line2D([0, 1], [0, 0], color=col))

# create a legend
plt.legend(artists, labels)

# all other customizations
```